# What is the Linux command to print the path of an environment variable

Tags: linux, command-line, environment-variables

I am relatively new to Linux.I have to install a library in Ubuntu to be able to use some functions it provides. It seemed to install fine, but gives error when I am testing it, which has led me to believe that I might have made a mistake in setting one of the environment variables for this library($OPENJPEG_DIR). Is there a way to print the path saved in this variable? I tried

ECHO $OPENJPEG_DIR

It did not work. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What library? How did you install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `env` to print the entire environment, which you could then pipe  to `grep` to find specific variables. Additionally, I noticed that in your question, you tried `ECHO $VARIABLE` which would probably yield an error because commands are case sensitive, so `echo $VARIABLE` might work as well.